# Custom Contact Form translation

Tags: magento-1.9, database, jquery, contact-us, translate

I have a custom contact form, I send all the fields I need, but I can not translate a field.

```
Realizou compra: Sim
Pedido: Pedido #100000001 - Total: R$105.00 - Data: 31-07-2017 - Status: pending
Status: 
Telefone: 14654165
Assunto: Assunto
Motivo: Reclamação
Comentario: Comentario
```

I would like to change the status "pending" to Pending and all others, but the table(sales_flat_order) on which I get this data is not translated. I checked and another table (sales_order_status) is translated, but would I have to create another command just to get this table? Would I translate from the table I'm picking up?

**controller**

```
    public function getOrderByEmail() { 
    $customer_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email) ; 

    foreach($orders as $order) { $date = $order->getCreatedAt();  $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); 
    $neworderjson = array('orderid'=>$order->getIncrementId(), 'status'=>$order->getStatus(), 'total'=>number_format((float)$order->getBaseGrandTotal(), 2, '.', ''), 'created'=>$date); 
    $orderjson[] = $neworderjson;
    } 
    return $orderjson; 
    }
```

**Template**

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input style="height:24px;" name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input style="height:24px;" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input style="height:24px;" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="tel" />
                </div>
            </li>
             <div class="select">
                <li>
                    <label for="f_f_assunto_ticket" class="required"><em>*</em>Motivo do contato</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select style="height:25px; padding:3px;" id="f_f_assunto_ticket" name="f_f_assunto_ticket" class="required-entry required-entry">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option value="Dúvidas Sobre Entrega">Dúvidas Sobre Entrega</option>
                            <option value="Dúvidas Sobre Pagamento">Dúvidas Sobre Pagamento</option>
                            <option value="Dicas de Presente">Dicas de Presente</option>
                            <option value="Reclamação">Reclamação</option>
                            <option value="Elogio">Elogio</option>
                            <option value="Confirmação de Dados">Confirmação de Dados</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </li>
            </div>            
            <div class="wide" id="pedido_option" style="display: none;">       
                <li>
                    <label for="f_compra" class="required"><em>*</em>Já realizou sua compra?</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select style="height:25px; padding:3px;" id="f_compra" name="f_compra" class="required-entry required-entry">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option value='Sim'>Sim</option>
                            <option value='Não'>Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </li>    
            </div>
            <div class="wide" id="pedido_txt" style="display: none;">            
                <li>
                    <label for="f_f_compra" class="required"><em>*</em>Já realizou sua compra?</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select style="height:25px; padding:3px;" id="f_f_compra" name="f_f_compra" class="required-entry required-entry select">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">-- Selecione --</option>
                            <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                            <option value="Não">Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </li>    
            </div>           
            <div id="pedido" style="display:none;">
                <li>
                    <label for="pedido" class="required"><em>*</em>Pedido</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                        <select style="height:25px; padding:3px;" name="orders" id="orders"></select>
                        </div>   
                </li>
            </div>
            <div id="pedidon" class="wide" style="display:none;">
                <li>
                        <label for="pedidon" class="required"><em>*</em>Pedido</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input style="width:262px;" name="pedidon" id="pedidon" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('pedidon')) ?>" value="" class="input-box required-entry" type="text" />              
                        </div>
                </li>
            </div>                    
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="assunto" class="required"><em>*</em>Assunto</label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input style="width:262px;" name="assunto" id="assunto" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('assunto')) ?>" value="" class="input-box required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <li>
            <label for="anexos">Anexar Arquivos</label>
            <div class="input-box">
                    <div class="MultiFile-wrap" id="attachment_wrap">
                        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="2000000" />
                        <input type="file" class="multi MultiFile-applied" name="anexos" id="anexos" value="">
                            <div class="MultiFile-list" id="attachment_wrap_list"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//Verifica o EMAIL para checar se tem algum PEDIDO cadastrado

$j("#email").focus(function() {}).blur(function() { 
    email = $j("#email").val(); 
        $j.ajax({url: "http://fol.projeto-gf.com.br/index.php/contato",
                type: "post",
                data: { type: "json", email: email },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result){ 
                $j("#orders" ).empty(); 
                    if (result == null) { 
                    } else { 
                        $j.each(result, function (index, data) { 
                        orderstring = "Pedido #" + result[index]["orderid"] + " - Total: R$" + result[index]["total"] + " - Data: " + result[index]["created"] + " - Status: " + result[index]["status"];
                        $j('#orders').append($j("<option></option>").attr("value",orderstring).text(orderstring)); 
            }) 
        } 
    }}); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, so, we are talking about a custom module in this case?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Can you add the code of your template?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside your config.xml you need to add the reference for the translation file:

   ```
   <frontend>
   <translate>
       <modules>
           <Custom_Module>
               <files>
                   <default>Custom_Module.csv</default>
               </files>
           </Custom_Module>
       </modules>
   </translate>
   ```
2. The texts inside your phtml should always needs to have the helper to translate the text:

   __('text to translate');?>
3. Set the translation file, create a folder inside app/locale/es_MX/Custom_Module.csv, and inside that file add your translations

"text to translate","Texto a traducir"

1. If you want the translation for the status, you only need to go to the admin -> System -> Order Status.
2. Then select the status you wanna to translate, select the store view, and put the translation right in the textbox.

Comment: How do I get the helpers to translate in phtml?

Comment: I created a CSV to translate what I wanted and added in the config.xml the data that you passed. Just missing from phtml, could you give me an example?

Comment: The data I want to translate is not input or something. They come from the database

Comment: Are you refering to $order->getStatus()?

Comment: Yes, that's right, he takes the data from this column.

Comment: I just edit my answer, please vote up if its ok for you :)

Comment: I do not want to change the translation for display in the store, watch my controller, the information that generates the status comes from the table (sales / order) but it is not translated, I would have to translate that.

Answer (score 0):

All Magento translations are used through the translation methods:

1. `$this->__('your word here');`
2. `Mage::helper('helper name')->__('your word here');`

Withoud one of these two methods Magento can't translate!

What you have to do is to check if your word have well a translation method.

Then to translate, you have to go to : `app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/locale/code_ISO/translate.csv` then you add your word like this: `"My word","My translation"`

You can check also if you are using a custom module if you have well declared your helper !

`app/code/codePool/Company/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" />
    ...
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <modulename>
                <class>Company_Modulename_Helper</class>
            </modulename>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    ...
```

`app/code/codePool/Company/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php`

```
class Company_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

You call it like this: `<?php Mage::helper('modulename')->__('My word') ?>`

> The **order status** can be translated through the admin configuration
>   `admin > system > order status`

Comment: I have declared helper, and the status of my requests are translated, has a translation table, what I want to say is that I get the status of a table that is not translated, if you repair there in the question can see that table that I get is (sales / order) which is a status without capital letter, it takes "raw" information, but so I do not need to change the table (sales / order) to (sales_order_status) <THAT IS TRANSLATED, what I Do I need to translate? Or would it be easier for me to get the STATUS information from the other table that has already been translated?